# Monthly search value in adwords api is much larger then in a Keyword Planner

Tags: php, google-ads

I am trying to use an adword api to get some keyword statistics. But what I see is that with a same parameters my monthly search volue is about 7 mln searches. While adword keyword planner shows around 400-500. I can provide php code with parameters I am setting.
Network settings:

```
$networkSetting = new NetworkSetting();
        $networkSetting->setTargetGoogleSearch(true);
        $networkSetting->setTargetSearchNetwork(false);
        $networkSetting->setTargetContentNetwork(false);
        $networkSetting->setTargetPartnerSearchNetwork(false);
```

Language is set to Russian following way:

```
 $languageParameter = new LanguageSearchParameter();
        $english = new Language();
        $english->setId(1031);
        $languageParameter->setLanguages([$english]);
        $searchParameters[] = $languageParameter;
```

Location is set to Ukraine:

```
$loc = array();
        $location = new location();
        $location->setId(2804); // Ukraine
        $loc[]=$location;
        $locationTargetParameter = new LocationSearchParameter();
        $locationTargetParameter->setLocations($loc);
        $searchParameters[] = $locationTargetParameter;
```

What Am I missing?